# La conexión java con mysql no funciona

Tags: java, mysql, conexión

Estaba Intentando crear un archivo que abre una base de datos mysql todo bien, asta que se me ocurrió hacerlo private static final, para poder utilizarlo en otros documentos, y no encuentra las variables.

```js
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexio {
    private static final String CONTROLADOR = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd";
    private static final String Usuario = "root";
    private static final String clave = "";
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("CONTROLADOR");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al cargar el controlador");
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
    public Connection conectar() {
        Connection conexion = null;
         try {
                Class.forName("controlador");
                conexion  =DriverManager.getConnection("url", "Usuario", "clave");          
                System.out.println("conexion establecida");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error en la conecion");
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }
        return conexion;
    }
  
}
```

y esta es la ventana del error que me aparece
[image]

Comment: Dice que CONTROLADOR no no fue encontrado, faltaría ver esa clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar los *string* que has puesto de parámetro en el método `getConnection()`.

Así:

```
Class.forName(CONTROLADOR);
conexion  = DriverManager.getConnection(url, Usuario, clave);
```

Y cualquier otra constante o objeto que hayas puesto como *string*.

No tengo donde probarlo en tiempo real, pero las CONSTANTES no se ponen entre paréntesis, y recuerda que debes ponerlas en mayúsculas.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexio {
    private static final String CONTROLADOR = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd";
    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String CLAVE = "";
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName(CONTROLADOR);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al cargar el controlador");
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
    public Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        Connection conexion = null;
         try {
                Class.forName(CONTROLADOR);
                conexion  = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, CLAVE);          
                System.out.println("conexion establecida");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error en la conecion");
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }
        return conexion;
    }
  
}
```